# Three.js: viewangle affects texture strength

Tags: javascript, three.js

[image]

My mesh has a baked shadow texture. 
Unfortunately I got a weird result If I move the camera to a steeper viewangle. 
What can I do to prevent this ?

```
loader.load( "mesh.js", function(geometry){
var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( {
map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( "texture.png" ),
}));
scene.add(mesh);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the example: http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_materials_texture_anisotropy

Use:

```
var maxAnisotropy = renderer.getMaxAnisotropy();
texture.anisotropy = maxAnisotropy;
```

If you would like to learn more, you can look up `Anisotropic Filtering`.